# Featuring Artist or Featured Artist?

Tags: grammar

May I ask if we would like to describe some artists who are presented in an exhibition, whether we should say they are 'featuring artists' or 'featured artists'?

Many thanks! :]

Comment: The exhibition features the artists, the artists are featured in the exhibition. On signs this can sometimes be confusing: "Great exhibition! Featuring Jan Doe!" is headlinese for "Our great exhibition is featuring Jane Doe".

Answer (score 6):

> There is a new exhibition *featuring* sculptors from around the world.
>   Brancusi is one of the *featured* artists.

In those sentences, *featuring sculptors...* modifies "exhibition", and *featured* modifies "artists".

Comment: As @oerkelens suggests above, sometimes parts of those sentences will be omitted in advertisements or headlines. But even where the subject is omitted the basic logic is always exactly as you say. Great explanation.